# Extract sub dictionary from keys that appear in a given list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Consider that I have a dictionary that looks like this:

{1=>a, 2=>b, 3=>c, 4=>d}

and a list that looks like this:

[1, 2, 3]

is there a method that'd return me a subdictionary only containing

{1=>a, 2=>b, 3=>c}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

a regular dict-comprehension would do that:

```
d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
keys = [1, 2, 3]

dct = {key: d[key] for key in keys}
print(dct)  # {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

---

there are 2 ways to handle keys in `keys` that are not in the original dictionary:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 7]

# default value None (dict.get allows to specify the default value)
dct = {key: d.get(key) for key in keys}
print(dct)  # {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 7: None}

# ignore the key if it is not in the original dict
dct = {key: d[key] for key in keys if key in d}
print(dct)  # {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Time limit :) Would you mind quickly showing me what's the syntax to check if the key from the list actually exists?

Comment: @kjanko added an update for that.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Thank you very much for your reply. It helps me. Is there a way that when a key is not found, I neither give a default value 'None' or ignore but store in a list so that I can later notify the user of missing keys? I tried `dct = {key: d[key] if key in d else missing.append(key) for key in keys}` but this still gives dct with None values for missing keys. I also tried `dct = {key: d[key] if key in d else missing.append(key) for key in set(keys).intersection(d.keys())}`. But this gave me empty dict and also empty missing list. Could you please help me

Comment: @Priya you could create `dct` as described above and then get the missing keys with `missing_keys = set(d) - set(keys)`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Thanks! But that is not what I want. But I want to list only the missing keys from `keys` that are not found in `d`. Eg: `d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}` `keys = [1, 2, 7, 8, 9]`. I just want to log `[7,8,9]` and create dct only with found values i.e., `print(dct)  # {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}`

Comment: @Priya that would be `set(keys) - set(d)` or - if you prefer a list: `[k for k in keys if k not in d]`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Hey, thanks! That works. But it gives me `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: None, 8: None, 9: None}`. Can I just extract it as `{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}`

Comment: @Priya sorry, i don't think i really understand your problem. what is your input and what is your desired output? you might even post that as a question (or here in the comments).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yes. I am almost near to answer. So I will just continue here. Eg: `d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}        keys = [1, 2, 7, 8, 9]` Output: `1. dct = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}  and   2. missing_keys = [7,8,9]`. With your suggestions above, I get output currently as `1. dct = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: None, 8: None, 9: None}` and `2. missing_keys=[7,8,9]`

Comment: @Priya `dct = {key: d[key] for key in set(keys) & set(d)}` and `missing_keys = set(keys) - set(d)` works for me.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Very very very thanks! This is what I was looking for. I also now got this with another way of creating one more sub-list with only keys found and then creating dict. but your answer seems so simple and much elegant. Mine was a round about. I will take your answer. Thanks a lot lot nd lot :)

Comment: no problem! happy to help. happy pythoning!

Comment: the second example seems not so pythonic, 
Why not use `{key: d[key] for key in keys if key in d}` is it for performance reasons ?
btw, the first one could by `{key: d.get(key) for key in keys}` which allow with a second argument to pass any other default than None